# Multi Threading and Multi tasking

Tags: linux

Can You Tell me what is the different between multi tasking and multi Threading (Linux)?

Answer (score 1):

Threads are executing in the same address space with their parent process, while tasks are not. Thus multiple threads created by one process can access its parent's memory.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference, in Linux, is that threads share most of their address space.  IE: if one thread makes a change to stuff in memory, other threads can see (and be affected by) that change.

In other OSes, the differences are more profound.  But in Linux, threads are almost (but not quite) processes in their own right -- they even have PIDs.

Answer (score 0):

**Multitasking**, in an operating system, is allowing a user to perform more than one computer task (such as the operation of an application program) at a time. The operating system is able to keep track of where you are in these tasks and go from one to the other without losing information

**Multithreading** is the ability of a program or an operating system process to manage its use by more than one user at a time and to even manage multiple requests by the same user without having to have multiple copies of the program running in the computer

Answer (score 0):

Multitasking: running different programs that share the same ***pool*** of memory, although in different ***slices*** of that ***pool*** of memory.

Multithreading: running different threads within the same program, sharing the same ***slice*** of memory.

Using both intensively would make more work for the CPU, because the CPU has to schedule and weigh in on which one to work on first, another side effect is that each task/thread will get less CPU resources and memory to share among them.

The best way to take advantage of these technologies is to make sure you use them when it is absolutely necessary.